# Constructing a complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is captured from a chapter talking about completeness of metric space in *Real Analysis*, Carothers, 1ed. And I have been confused by an example of construction of a complete metric space:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
In the middle of this paragraph, the author claimed that "Given a metric space M, we need to construct a complete space that is "big enough" to contain M isometrically. One way to accomplish this is to consider the collection of all bounded, real-valued functions on M.( This is roughly analogues to using the power set of M when looking for a set that is bigger than M.)". I have 2 questions about it:

1. why can we accomplish by considering the collection of all bounded, real-valued functions on M? I means there seems to be no any relationship between collection of all bounded, real-valued functions on M and completion of M.
2. Similar to question1, what is the relationship between using the power set of M when looking for a set that is bigger than M and collection of all bounded, real-valued functions on M.

Comment: The proofs I have seen deal with sequences and equivalence classes ($\{x_n\} \sim \{y_n\}$ iff $d(x_n,y_n) \to 0$). I don't have the book, so I'm guessing that this is where the author goes next.

Comment: @copper.hat: So u mean the "big enough" space that will be constructed is a new space which is not only isometical to M but complete when comparing to M and nevertheless may not contain M??

Comment: @copper.hat: I've attached the following content.

Comment: @copper.hat: I mean the "big enough" space above is not M but a replica of a completion of M.

Comment: Frank, a completion is usually another space $M'$ along with a distance preserving map (an isometry) $i : M \to M'$  that maps $M$ into $M'$. The space $M'$ must be 'bigger' in some sense since it contains a copy of $M$ and some more points, but 'bigger' is a bit vague. For example, a completion of $((0,1), |\cdot|)$ is $([0,1], |\cdot|)$ with $i$ being the identity map. Another completion of the same space is the set of Cauchy sequences with values in $(0,1)$, $i(x) = (x,x,x,x,...)$, and $d((x_1,x_2,...),(y_1,y_2,...)) = \lim_n d(x_n,y_n)$.

Comment: @copper.hat: you mean the set of all Cauchy sequences which converges to real numbers in(0,1) can be the completion of (0,1)? why? I cannot understand ur last example:"d((x1,x2,...),(y1,y2,...))=limnd(xn,yn)" means the distance between vector (x1,x2,...) and vector (y1,y2,...) which are in space i((0,1)) equals to the distance between their last elements?

Answer (score 1):

As copper.hat pointed out three minutes ago, there are other constructions for the completion of a metric space. The completion of $M$ can be constructed as a set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in $M$. You can look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Completion) for an overview or in any book on topology. The definition using equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences is perhaps more intuitive in the sense that the definition of a complete metric space is precisely that Cauchy sequences are converging. Thus the intuition in this construction is just to add the "missing" limit points.

There is another argument in favor of the construction involving Cauchy sequences. If you consider uniform spaces (an abstract version of metric spaces), then the construction using Cauchy sequences can be generalized (by using Cauchy filters), but the construction using norms does not seem to carry over to the general case.

Comment: So u mean the "big enough" space that will be constructed is a new space which is not only isometical to M but complete when comparing to M and nevertheless may not contain M??